# Move data in Excel

Tags: excel

I am now having problem moving data in Excel. It has thousands of item in my excel(Name and barcode). My data is in this format.

[image]

I want to change like that

[image]

How can i change it? I am new excel user. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! i got it by using Macro code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. I use following Macro code and got it. Thanks! 4 = start row index and 501 is last row index.

```
Sub MoveColumn()

For i = 4 To 501 Step 1
    Range("B" & i).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C" & (i - 1) & "").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("" & i & ":" & i).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next
End Sub
```